# If checkbox is checked, get the contents of other inputs

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

I'm trying to get contents of 'grouped' `inputs`, depending on whether the checkbox of that 'group' is checked. I then want to take the contents of each input in the group and put it in an `array`. Below are two group examples generated by a PHP loop, each group `input` will have a group associated number at the end of the name. If need be, I can change the names, ID's, etc.

```
// Group 1
<input name="hold_1" id="hold_1" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input name="hold_id_1" id="hold_id_1" value="200" type="hidden">
<input name="hold_date_1" id="hold_date_1" value="2014" type="text">

// Group 2
<input name="hold_2" id="hold_2" value="2" type="checkbox">
<input name="hold_id_2" id="hold_id_2" value="250" type="hidden">
<input name="hold_date_2" id="hold_date_2" value="2014" type="text">
```

This is the JQuery statement that I could use some help with. This version successfully gets all the `input` values, but doesn't distinguish between which group is checked.

```
        var inputs = $('input'), dataArray = {};
        $.each(inputs, function (index, input) {
            dataArray[$(input).attr('id')] = $(input).val();
        });
```

So far, by using various methods, I've only been able to get all the input values (regardless of whether checked), or only checkbox values, or some other data that isn't useful to me.

In case it helps, here's the `.ajax` post that uses the that data array. This part is working fine.

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "something.php",
                data: dataArray,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(doStuff);
                }
            });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so you want to get only checked groups?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the values in each input? or the name appended to each one?

Comment: Yes, only want info from groups that are checked. For example if `hold_1` is checked, I need the values of `hold_1`, `hold_id_1`and `hold_date_1` but not any info from group `2`.  If group `2` is also checked, I'll need it's equivalent info as well. I hope that make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple approach which allows you to get values of the elements whose corresponding checkbox is checked.

```
var inputs = $('input'), 
    checks = inputs.filter(':checkbox'),
    dataArray = {};

$.each(inputs, function (index, input) {
    var groupCheckbox = checks.filter('#' + input.id.replace(/_.*_/, '_'));
    if (groupCheckbox.is(':checked')) {
        dataArray[input.id] = $(input).val();    
    }
});
```

The only trick here is how id of the checkbox is built: by replacing central part of input id `hold_date_1` with `_`.

Check interactive demo below.

```js
function getData() {
    var inputs = $('input'), 
        checks = inputs.filter(':checkbox'),
        dataArray = {};
    
    $.each(inputs, function (index, input) {
        var groupCheckbox = checks.filter('#' + input.id.replace(/_.*_/, '_'));
        if (groupCheckbox.is(':checked')) {
            dataArray[input.id] = $(input).val();    
        }
    });
    
    return dataArray;
}

$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var data = getData();
    alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="hold_1" id="hold_1" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input name="hold_id_1" id="hold_id_1" value="200" type="hidden">
<input name="hold_date_1" id="hold_date_1" value="2014" type="text">

<input name="hold_2" id="hold_2" value="2" type="checkbox">
<input name="hold_id_2" id="hold_id_2" value="250" type="hidden">
<input name="hold_date_2" id="hold_date_2" value="2014" type="text">
```

Comment: The results when I click each checkbox are exactly what I want/need. I have a question about your `checks.filter` section and your last comment... I can easily change the ID and Names to contain a single `_` instead of having two, and if so, would the statement then be `checks.filter('_')`?

Comment: Can you post how ids would look after you change them with single `_`? Like `hold1_name`?

Comment: Sure, I could use that name (`hold1_name`), but I was thinking more along the lines of `holdName_1` just to separate the group instances with the last char in the name. I have a hard time deciphering regex's and really just want to understand your intent and the use of `checks.filter`. I hope that make more sense.

Comment: In this case regexp will be more complex: https://regex101.com/r/sM4rR3/1 A demo with this name pattern http://jsfiddle.net/hjn9s6mm/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle link and especially the regex101 link - very helpful! I was surprised that changing the id from one `_` to two make it more complex. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Well actually it's not change from two `_` to single one, it's also change from _ separator to lowercaseUppercase boundary which also makes it more complex.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see that now. I was just playing with the regex link, unbelievable helpful. So much easier to wrap my inexperienced brain around the concept. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

with pure javascript you can do this

```js
function checkAllBoxes () {
    var checkedBox = document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]:checked");
    
    for(var i in checkedBox) {
       console.log(checkedBox[i])
    }
}

var checkAll = document.querySelector("#checkAll");

checkAll.addEventListener("click", checkAllBoxes, false);
```

```html
<input name=hold_1 id=hold_1 value=1 type=checkbox />
<input name=hold_id_1 id=hold_id_1 value=200 hidden />
<input name=hold_date_1 id=hold_date_1 value=2014 type=text />

<input name=hold_2 id=hold_2 value=2 type=checkbox />
<input name=hold_id_2 id=hold_id_2 value=250 hidden />
<input name=hold_date_2 id=hold_date_2 value=2014 type=text />

<input id=checkAll type=button value=checkMe />
```

Comment: This looks like a 'make a check to all boxes' script. If so, what I'm looking for is 'which boxes are checked' script. Sorry if I wasn't clear or not understanding your intent.